# Django request.body.decode security

Tags: json, django, security

I have a view set up to work with datatables; it accepts the data posted by datatables in JSON format, so I use:

```
json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
```

to grab the data I need to search, sort, and paginate my tables via ajax. All of this works, but I'm worried that loading the body of the request in this way could leave me open to attacks, especially since I could be loading arbitrary data in that line.

What can/should I do to make sure this doesn't leave the code open to exploitation?

Note: I am using csrf tokens in each request. I'm worried more about direct attacks from a malicious user of the system.

Comment: You can use [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/) to filter out the values that you want.

Comment: What specifically are you worried about? Loading JSON data in itself will not open you up to any attacks, but if you use that data for sensitive tasks you will need to clean, validate and/or escape it. Django forms are one option, as mentioned by geeky_sh, though if you are using JSON you might also want to take a look at django-rest-framework.